# Updating timestamp with custom format (dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss.FFFFFFF)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

How to write a statement that will update the date field in database with `dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss.FFFFFFF` format.

I have select query which return the require string

```
SELECT FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss.FFFFFFF')
```

I tried with

```
update ORDER 
set timedate=FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss.FFFFFFF') 
WHERE ID='288'
```

But returning error :

> SQL Error [8152] [22001]: String or binary data would be truncated.
>    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would 
>   be truncated.

My field datatype is varchar 27

```
CREATE TABLE AYAM.dbo.ORDER (
ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
TIMEDATE varchar(27) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_ORDER_DATA PRIMARY KEY (ID,TIMEDATE)
) GO;
```

I am using MSSQL 2016

Comment: What's the datatype? If it's a `datetime2` as it should be, why are you updating it with a `varchar` value?

Comment: Added datatype into my question @HoneyBadger

Comment: First of all: Why do you store datetimes in a varchar? That doesn't seem to make sense. Then `varchar(16)`? `dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss.FFFFFFF`is 27 characters long - 9 characters too many for your type.

Comment: Keep that data in *appropriate* data types (here, `datetime2`) and leave *formatting* concerns to the front-end application/reporting tools. Storing as a string in `dd/MM/yyyy...` format is a terrible decision - since you've lost any ability to process this data *as* datetime data and it doesn't even sort sensibly. (e.g. 1st February sorts before 2nd January in an ascending sort)

Comment: It a other party database design. I connected to them and just need to insert and update data with the required format when order arrive or updated

Comment: @RobbiNespu Is this your actual code or is the update statement you posted an example of what your application **should** be executing? Why ask? Because your error indicates java is in use - which you did not tag directly. So perhaps the problem is how you generate/execute this statement and not with the logic you are supposed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you ask for FFFFFFF when CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function returns only 3 decimal numbers? Use SYSDATETIME() function to get better precision.

I was unable to re-produce the error. What SQL Server version do you use?

```
create table #test (timedate varchar(27))
insert into #test VALUES ('test');
update #test 
set timedate=FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss.FFFFFFF') 
select * from #test
drop table #test
```

The output is: 18/09/2017 12:09:44.6914345

UPDATED:
the same test was done using your table structure. No errors ...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[ORDER] (TIMEDATE) VALUES ('test')
GO 300


update [ORDER] 
set timedate=FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss.FFFFFFF') 
WHERE ID='288'
```

Comment: MSSQL 2016 database

Comment: I tested it on 2016 also. Can you provide actual table definition?

Comment: Added my DDL table